# Configure Mandrill with Meteor fail

Tags: javascript, email, meteor, mandrill

I always get error saying:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'config' of undefined.

This is my startup function on `server.js`. What do I do wrong?

```js
Meteor.startup(function() {
 return Meteor.Mandrill.config({
   username: "SMTP Username",
   key: "Valid API Key",
   password: "Valid API Key",
   port: "587",
   host:"smtp.mandrillapp.com"
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meteor startup function is not designed to return something, this is your first error.
On an other hand, I can see on [their documentation](https://atmospherejs.com/wylio/mandrill) that you have to configure the object Mandrill directly.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    // server code
    Mandrill.config({
          username: "SMTP Username",
          key: "Valid API Key",
          password: "Valid API Key",
          port: "587",
          host:"smtp.mandrillapp.com"
        // baseUrl: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/'  // update this in case Mandrill changes its API endpoint URL or version
    });

    // you can put a Meteor startup here if you want : 
    Meteor.startup(function() {
        // Do somthing else, like populating, ...
    });
}
```